# Is the "to" required in "the person (to) whom I granted freedom"?

Tags: prepositions, relative-clauses

I had this phrase *"the person whom I granted freedom"* in something I wrote; a friend maintains that it must be *"the person* **to** *whom I granted freedom."*

Comment: That one is also correct, but it's the relative clause formed from _I granted freedom to the person_, rather than what you wrote, which is the relative clause formed from _I granted the person freedom_ (i.e, with the dative alternation, but without _to_, though you could also strand the preposition _to_ at the end, if you wanted to -- it adds nothing in any event).

Comment: It's General Reference that [it "should" be ***whom***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/who-or-whom) here. But some people *never* use it any more. On the other hand, those who use it at all will almost certainly get it right in *this specific context*, because of the giveaway preposition ***to*** (which they would normally expect to be present).

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I don't think he's asking about who/whom but about whether it's OK to omit the "to".  I agree that one would normally expect "to" to be present.

Comment: The person whom he manumitted

Comment: No, _whom_ is allowed, but not required. _Who_ works just as well, "technically". But traditionalists will always say that _whom_ is preferred, which is false. Some prefer it (they do), but many don't bother with it at all.

Comment: @Lynn,John: I don't use *whom* very often in general, and in OP's exact context I might not even bother with *who* either (I'm quite comfortable with just *"the person I granted freedom [**to**]"*). But if I'm going to use either *who* or *whom* in this type of construction I would usually precede it by *to* - and ***if*** I did that, I would be much more likely to follow it with *whom* rather than *who*. My point is that the presence of the preposition calls attention to the fact that it's an object rather than subject. That nudges me into a "correct" usage which I otherwise largely ignore.

Comment: Simplify! *the person I freed*

Answer (score 1):

"The person to whom I granted freedom" seems natural to me. Or "The person whom I freed".

"...whom I granted..." grates on my ear; it sounds as if you are about to give the person to someone else.